# intent to take bold or italic from layout to another layout

Tags: java, android-intent

my code is to change edittext to bold or italic . 
this code to write a text in editText and send it to another layout when touch in image1 
this has intent to take text and size of text 
i want another intent to take the bold or italic also .

```
 public class Graduation extends ActionBarActivity {
Button button;
ImageView imageView ;
 Spinner spinner;
 int fontSizeInt;
String[]items = { "12", "16", "18", "20", "24", "28" , "30" };

 int fontSizeFamily;

 EditText et;
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graduation);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
              new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                          int arg2, long arg3) {
                    int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

                    try
                    {
                        fontSizeInt = Integer.parseInt(items[position]);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        fontSizeInt = 12; // Default size.
                    }
                    et.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) fontSizeInt);
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  }
                  @Override
                  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  }
              }); 

    addListenerOnImageg1() ;
    addListenerOnButton1();
    addListenerOnButton2();
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

}

public void addListenerOnButton1() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            et.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);   

        }

    }); } 
public void addListenerOnButton2() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            et.setTypeface(null,Typeface.ITALIC);   

        }

    }); }



 public void addListenerOnImageg1() {

    final Context context = this;

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.g1);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, g1.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
      Intent intent1 = new Intent(context , g1.class); 
      intent1.putExtra("fn" , et.getText().toString());
      intent1.putExtra("font_size", fontSizeInt);
      startActivity(intent1);
       // here is the intent I want to take a style also to another layout 

        }

    }); }
```

also i have .xml file which has all the content i want .. 
something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backf"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter your Text Here  : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TableRow>
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="B" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:text="I" />

 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="choose your card : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/g1"
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="111dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/g1" />
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/g2"
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="111dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/g2" />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/g3"
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="111dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/g3" />
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/g4"
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="111dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/g4" />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/g5"
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="111dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/g5" />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/g6"
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="111dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/g6" />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/g7"
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="111dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/g7" />

 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

so my text goes to another layout with no change so when i click bold button the change happen on editText but when i click image the text go to image1 layout without bold

Comment: You need to send the style of the edittext to another layout as well as the text itself.

Comment: There is more than one way. For example, when you're clicking "italic" or "bold" buttons, save in some boolean variables whether your bold and italic are on or off.  Then pass these booleans along with the text to the next activity, in which you can apply bold/italic accordingly.